# Is there a Drupal.org issue queues module? Which module does Drupal.org use?

Tags: 7, community-official-site

Does Drupal.org use a module for its project issues tracking? I would like to implement it on our D7 site.

Does this exist as a module or is this something proprietary to drupal.org? If it is not a module, what is the closest I can get for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Project](https://drupal.org/project/project) project, and [Project issue tracker](https://drupal.org/project/project_issue) project, together make up most of the functionality that you are looking for. Since you ask about D7, it's worth noting that the modules are currently under upgrade to D7.

Project:

> Projects are generally assumed to represent software that has source code, releases, and so on.

Project issue tracker:

> It allows users to submit issues (bug reports, feature requests, tasks, etc) and enables teams to track their progress.

Comment: These show d5 and d6 versions available and are incompatible with views 3. Anything out there for d7?

Comment: In the description of "Project" you will find links to the D7 effort. I'll avoid posting links in the comment that the project page is more likely to contain up-to-date links.